# Making Input Text to open up drop down list in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive in AngularJS which acts as Input and Select box together. Just like when you type in search textbox a dropdown list popups for assisting user to select. The selection is working fine via mouseclick, but I want my user to use arrow keys to move up and down and select on enter as well. Below is my HTML , CSS and Javascript code. Your quick assistance in this regard will be appreciated.

```
/*******CSS Code******/

.input-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.input-dropdown .dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: #EEE;
}
.input-dropdown .dropdown div {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
.input-dropdown input:focus + .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

/*******AngularJS Code*****************/

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.values = ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'IE'];
        $scope.pick = function (value) {
            console.log('Picked', value)
        };
    });

    app.directive('inputDropdown', function ($compile) {

        var template =
    '<input ng-model="ngModel">' +
    '<div class="dropdown">' +
        '<div ng-repeat="value in list | filter: ngModel">' +
            '<div ng-mousedown="select($event, value)">{{value}}</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                list: '=',
                onSelect: '&'
            },
            template: template,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.addClass('input-dropdown');
                scope.select = function (e, value) {
                    scope.ngModel = value;
                    scope.onSelect({ $event: e, value: value });
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

HTML Code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <input-dropdown ng-model="preference" list="values" on-select="pick(value)"></input-dropdown> {{preference}}



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could probably add an `ng-keypress` to one of your `<div>`s  and pass `$event` to a a function in your directive's controller to determine which key is pressed down. You could then hold onto a "selectedDiv" variable in your list which you would increment/decrement based upon which key was pressed down.

Comment: Here's a [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/oEQGBsv8MqGkbIYZ5Kaj?p=preview).

Comment: Consider using [Bootstrap Dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) for the CSS. It has all the classes for a working dropdown. The directive then only needs to manipulate the list and the classes and integrate it with the model. Also consider using the built-in [Angular jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) to bind DOM events such as `mousedown`, `keypress`, `focusin`, etc.